# Write a bash script that accepts a time duration as arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, time, duration

I'm looking for a `bash` script that can parse a time duration.

If three arguments are given, they represent hours, minutes, and seconds. If two arguments are given, they represent minutes and seconds, with the hours zero.

Comment: The arguments do not represent a time of day- they represnt a duration, how long it takes to do something.

Comment: evaluate using `sleep`?

Comment: @ReubenL.: can you explain how you can parse with `sleep`?

Comment: Why are you doing this? This isn't a homework, is it?

Answer (score 4):

What about the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

h=0
if [ "$#" -ge 3 ]
then
   h=$1
   shift
fi
sec=$((3600*$h+60*$1+$2))

echo "The total number of seconds is $sec"
```

Since the question does not specify what you aim to do with the given time, the program calculates the total number of seconds. Furthermore perhaps it is useful to do a check if at least two arguments are given.

The script uses the [**`shift`**](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) operation, the shift makes makes `$1 := $2`; `$2 := $3`, etc. In other words, the first argument is processed, and then you "pretend" it never existed.

By default you set `h` to zero, and only if the number of arguments is greater than or equal to `3`, it will set `h`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about shift. Seems to be a useful feature.

Comment: `shift` is handy in [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161887/my-self-shift-in-perl-an-explanation) languages

Answer (score 2):

This is a more or less general solution for that type of task. Sorry, if it is a monkeycode, but I think it is sufficient:

```
gettime() {
    params=(
        years months weeks days hours minutes seconds
    )
    for i in `seq ${#params}`; do
        param_i=$((${#params} - i + 1)) # reversed params index
        [ $i -le $# ] && {
            eval "local ${params[$param_i]}=\$$(($# - i + 1))"
        } || {
            eval "local ${params[$param_i]}=0"
        }
        eval "echo ${params[$param_i]} '==' \$${params[$param_i]}" # debug output
    done
}
```

Here's the sample output:

```
$ gettime 3 4 5 6 7

seconds == 7
minutes == 6
hours == 5
days == 4
weeks == 3
months == 0
years == 0
```

Note, that the shell you are using must be not only support POSIX standards, but also arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First Argument: $1

Second Argument: $2

Third Argument: $3

and so on...

Example:

```
bash-2.05a$ ./parseDuration.sh 13 25 25
13 hours and 25 minutes and 25 seconds
bash-2.05a$ cat ./parseDuration.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 hours and $2 minutes and $3 seconds"
```

Comment: I think the OP means that if two arguments are given, that the first and second are interpreted as minutes and seconds respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how do I normalize. for instance we do not say "two minutes and sixty-five seconds". rather, we say "three minutes and five seconds. Basically, how can I overflow the value to the next higher unit. The renge is 00-59.